# Programatically creating a content type in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I'm creating an Orchard module and as part of my migration I need to create a new content type. I am able to inject an instance of IContentManager into my migration class which allows me to create new content items but I haven't been able to figure out how to create a new content type.

Can someone describe how this is done (code examples would be great)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to inject content manager. There are many, many examples of that throughout the code. In fact, you can take pretty much any migration, in any module, and find something like this:

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("BlogPost",
    cfg => cfg
           .WithPart("BlogPostPart")
           .WithPart("CommonPart", p => p
           .WithSetting("DateEditorSettings.ShowDateEditor", "true"))
           .WithPart("PublishLaterPart")
           .WithPart("RoutePart")
           .WithPart("BodyPart")
);
```

Comment: "You can't add a field to a **content type**, you always add it to a **content part**. It's just that if that part has the same name as the type, **nice magical things happen**." [Bertrand Le Roy on Codeplex](https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/397426), emphasis add.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Can you succinctly explain what "magical things" actually happen? I am guessing that the same name for the type and part helps NHibernate do some "magic", just confused exactly as to what the "magic" is.

Comment: When you add a `ContentPart` to a `ContentType`, and both have the same name, then the `ContentPart` does not appear in Orchard's *Content Definition* UI.  Also, any `ContentFields` that you programmatically add to the `ContentPart` appear - in the user interface - to belong to the `ContentType`. Take the Page Type for instance. From the Content Definition UI, you can add Fields to the Page Type, and they appear to belong to the Page Type, but they don't. They belong to the Page Part, even though there is no Page Part in the user interface. That Part exists behind the scenes.

Comment: I spent days figuring this out... Isn't this documented anywhere?

Comment: It is. For instance, http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Getting-Started-with-Modules-Part-1#Datamigrations, or http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-a-module-with-a-simple-text-editor#PuttingitAllTogetherintoaContentType

Answer (score 1):

Ey, here you have another sample of part and content type definition.

```
// PART DEFINITION
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("ProductPart", p => p

.WithDescription("Product part")

    // To select other contents ( on this example "ProductPresentation" content type )
.WithField("ProductPresentation", f => f
    .OfType("ContentPickerField")
    .WithDisplayName("Product presentation")
    .WithSetting("ContentPickerFieldSettings.Required", "True")
    .WithSetting("ContentPickerFieldSettings.Multiple", "True")
    .WithSetting("ContentPickerFieldSettings.ShowContentTab", "True")
    .WithSetting("ContentPickerFieldSettings.Hint", "Please select product's presentation")
    .WithSetting("ContentPickerFieldSettings.DisplayedContentTypes", "ProductPresentation")
)

// To select images
.WithField("ProductImageField", f => f
    .OfType("MediaLibraryPickerField")
    .WithDisplayName("Product image")
    .WithSetting("MediaLibraryPickerFieldSettings.Hint", "Please select product's image")
    .WithSetting("MediaLibraryPickerFieldSettings.Required", "True")
    .WithSetting("MediaLibraryPickerFieldSettings.Multiple", "False")

)

// To add a taxonomy field called "ProductLines"
.WithField("Category", fcfg => fcfg
    .OfType("TaxonomyField")
    .WithDisplayName("Category")
    .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.Taxonomy", "ProductLines")
    .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.LeavesOnly", "True")
    .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.Required", "True")
    .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.SingleChoice", "False")
    .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.Autocomplete", "False")
    .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.AllowCustomTerms", "False")
    .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.Hint", "Please select product's category")
    )

.Attachable()
);


// CONTENT TYPE DEFINITION
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Product", cfg => cfg
                .DisplayedAs("Product")
                .WithPart(
                    "CommonPart", c => c
                        .WithSetting("DateEditorSettings.ShowDateEditor", "False")
                        .WithSetting("OwnerEditorSettings.ShowOwnerEditor", "False")
                    )
                    .WithPart("ProductPart")
                    .WithPart("TitlePart", c => c.WithSetting("Hint", "Please enter the product name"))
                    .WithPart("BodyPart", c => c.WithSetting("Hint", "Please enter the product description"))
                    .WithPart("LocalizationPart")

                    .WithPart("AutoroutePart", partBuilder => partBuilder
                    .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.AllowCustomPattern", "true")
                    .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.AutomaticAdjustmentOnEdit", "true")
                    .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.PatternDefinitions", "[{Name:'Product Title', Pattern: 'product/{Content.Slug}', Description: 'product/title-product'}]"))

                .Listable()
                .Draftable()
                .Creatable()
                .Securable()
                .Indexed()
                );
```